# Dirac equation for the Kagome lattice

Tags: dirac-equation, second-quantization, lattice-model, graphene, tight-binding

## Background

To model graphene we often use a nearest-neighbour tight-binding Hamiltonian
$$H = - t \sum_{<ij>} c^{\dagger}_i c_j$$
embedded on a hexagonal lattice. By performing a Fourier transformation
$$c_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_\mathbf{k} e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}_i} c_{\mathbf{k}},$$
and introducing the vector $\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{K}- \mathbf{k}$, where $\mathbf{K}$ is one of the Dirac points we can show that the eigenvalue problem becomes a Dirac equation, with well-defined eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

## The problem

I tried to do the same for the Kagome lattice. The primitive lattice vectors are $\mathbf{a}_1 = a(1,0)$ and $\mathbf{a}_2 = a(1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$. The basis atoms are located at $\mathbf{r}_1 = 0$, $\mathbf{r}_2 = \mathbf{a}_1/2$, and $\mathbf{r}_3 = \mathbf{a}_2/2$. Here $a$ is the lattice spacing.

I found that if we embed the Hamiltonian above on the Kagome lattice and perform a Fourier transformation we obtain
$$H = \sum_{\mathbf{k}} \phi^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k}} H_{\mathbf{k}} \phi_{\mathbf{k}}$$
where
$$
H_{\mathbf{k}} = -t
\begin{bmatrix}
 0& 2\cos\left(\frac{\mathbf{k\cdot \mathbf{a}_1}}{2} \right) & 2\cos\left(\frac{\mathbf{k\cdot \mathbf{a}_2}}{2} \right)\\
2\cos\left(\frac{\mathbf{k\cdot \mathbf{a}_1}}{2} \right) & 0 & 2\cos\left(\frac{\mathbf{k\cdot \left(\mathbf{a}_1-\mathbf{a}_2\right)}}{2} \right)\\
2\cos\left(\frac{\mathbf{k\cdot \mathbf{a}_2}}{2} \right)& 2\cos\left(\frac{\mathbf{k\cdot \left(\mathbf{a}_1-\mathbf{a}_2\right)}}{2} \right) & 0
 \end{bmatrix},
$$
and $\phi_{\mathbf{k}} = (A_{\mathbf{k}},B_{\mathbf{k}},C_{\mathbf{k}})$ are creation/annhilation operators acting on the three different sublattices denoted by $A$, $B$, and $C$.
I found the three eigenvalues consistent with literature
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&E_1 = 2t,\\
&E_2 = -t \left\{ 1 + \sqrt{3 + 2 \left[ \cos k_xa + \cos \frac{k_x-\sqrt{3}k_y}{2}a + \cos \frac{k_x+\sqrt{3}k_y}{2}a \right]} \right\},\\
&E_3 = -t \left\{ 1 - \sqrt{3 + 2 \left[ \cos k_xa + \cos \frac{k_x-\sqrt{3}k_y}{2}a + \cos \frac{k_x+\sqrt{3}k_y}{2}a \right]} \right\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I then wanted to construct a low-energy theory close to the point $\mathbf{K}=\left(\frac{4 \pi}{3a},0\right)$. So I defined $\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{k} - \mathbf{K}$, and performed Taylor expansions of the cosines for small $|\mathbf{q}|a \ll 1$. When the dust settled I obtained
\begin{equation}
H_{\mathbf{K}+ \mathbf{q}} = -t
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x & 1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x - \frac{3}{4}y\\
  -1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x & 0 &  1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x + \frac{3}{4}y\\
 1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x - \frac{3}{4}y &  1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x + \frac{3}{4}y & 0
 \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where I defined $x = q_x a$, and $y=q_y a$. However, when I calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors I do no longer obtain the eigenvalue $E_1 = 2t$. In fact
$$\det \left(H_{\mathbf{K} + \mathbf{q}} - 2t I_{3\times 3} \right) = \frac{3}{16}t^3 \left( x^2\left(6 + \sqrt{3} x \right) - 3 \left(-2+\sqrt{3} x \right) y^2\right) \neq 0.$$

My question is then how can I construct a low-energy theory in the vicinity of the K-point without ''loosing'' the exact eigenvalue.

Comment: Since you already have the eigenvalues, you could obtain the general eigenvectors and then expand them near the point of interest. Also, eigenvalue $E=2t$ does not change when you expand in $k$, so you knwo a root of the cubic equation, and can reduce it to a quadratic one. It is relying on Mathematica for problems solvable by hand that seems to mislead you :)

Comment: Thanks for you comment! The determinant of the matrix $\H_{\mathbf{K} + \mathbf{q}} - 2t I $ is not zero. I think this means that something goes wrong when I perform the expansion. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Btw, $t$ seems to be missing in your $H_k$.

Comment: added now, thanks

Comment: Since the diagonal elements are zero, the characteristic equation is readily a depressed cubic and you can write the answer using Cardano formula or the trigonometric method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation

Comment: Does the model on the kagome lattice have dirac points at the points you look at?

Comment: yes, the two bands $E_2$ and $E_3$ touch at the K-point given above